# Sonatype Nexus - Central repository : In Service - Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable

Tags: nexus

I'm sorry about this question, but I havn't found any solution to this, yet.
My nexus install worked very well, but suddenly I realized that default repositories are blocked (Central, Apache snapshoot, Codehouse). OK, Codehouse is a different story.

I have tried the followings:
- increase nexus allocated memory (https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465178-Adjusting-memory-allocated-to-Nexus)
- go throogh these trouble shooting tips (https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464518-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Download-Failures)
- tried to use ?describe feature to find out more info,
- tried to repair configurations if neccessary, but ...

nothing helped me.
Do you have any idea what should I do?

Thanks,

altjeno

Answer (score 1):

Nexus automatically blocks repositories when there are network errors so that misbehaving remotes won't deplete the connection thread pool.  When connectivity is restored the repositories will be automatically unblocked.

Check the nexus logs. Most likely you'll find your corporate firewall is blocking outbound access to the internet.